# MOSS: How to quickly get total count of all webs in a Site Collection?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, moss

Is there a way to get a total count of all webs in a Site Collection, without enumerating through them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SPSite.AllWebs.Count` is optimized to return this information without fully enumerating.

Comment: I was under the impression that SPSite doesn't work for MOSS 2007? or is that just because I have powershell version `2 0 -1 -1` which has nothing except `loadwithpartialname`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have enormous amount of sites, use the site hierachy to copy and paste the list to excel to get a quick count for a single site collection.
https://{your site}/_layouts/vsubwebs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on this a few weeks back and was only able to find information (like [this](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Recursively-listing-all-MOSS-Site-Collections-and-Sub-Sites.aspx)) on enumerating the site collections / sites using stsadm.

There are also third-party tools that can help you achieve this goal.  Maybe something from [Nintex](http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Products/Pages/NintexReporting2008.aspx) or [Metalogix](http://www.metalogix.net/Products/Universal-SharePoint-Manager/)?  I've heard vendors make suggestions but we've never done anything more than wish for them.